# Быстрое преобразование Фурье, как работать с комплексными числами, если их нет

Tags: c#, fft

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace BPF
{
    public static class danie
    {
        public static Complex[] X;
        public static Complex[] Y;

        public static Complex[] FastPFurie;

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            danie.X = GetDan("exaX.txt");
            danie.Y = GetDan("exa.txt");
            FFT ff = new FFT();
            danie.FastPFurie=FFT.fft(danie.X);
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.ShowDialog();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static int n = 0;


        public static Complex[] GetDan(string fail)//получение данных из файла
        {
            n = 0;
            string s = "";
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fail);
            s = r.ReadLine();
            n = s.Split(' ').Length;
            Complex[] matrix = new Complex[n];
            string[] l = s.Split(' ');
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                matrix[k] = Convert.ToDouble(l[k]);
            }
            r.Close();
            return matrix;
        }
    }

}
```

-

```
public class FFT
{
    /// Вычисление поворачивающего модуля e^(-i*2*PI*k/N)

    private static Complex w(int k, int N)
    {
        if (k % N == 0) return 1;
        double arg = -2 * Math.PI * k / N;
        return new Complex(Math.Cos(arg), Math.Sin(arg));
    }

    /// Возвращает спектр сигнала

    /// <param name="x">Массив значений сигнала. Количество значений должно быть степенью 2</param>
    /// <returns>Массив со значениями спектра сигнала</returns>
    public static Complex[] fft(Complex[] x)
    {
        Complex[] X;
        int N = x.Length;
        if (N == 2)
        {
            X = new Complex[2];
            X[0] = x[0] + x[1];
            X[1] = x[0] - x[1];
        }
        else
        {
            Complex[] x_even = new Complex[N / 2];
            Complex[] x_odd = new Complex[N / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
            {
                x_even[i] = x[2 * i];
                x_odd[i] = x[2 * i + 1];
            }
            Complex[] X_even = fft(x_even);
            Complex[] X_odd = fft(x_odd);
            X = new Complex[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
            {
                X[i] = X_even[i] + w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
                X[i + N / 2] = X_even[i] - w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
            }
        }
        return X;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Центровка массива значений полученных в fft (спектральная составляющая при нулевой частоте будет в центре массива)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="X">Массив значений полученный в fft</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Complex[] nfft(Complex[] X)
    {
        int N = X.Length;
        Complex[] X_n = new Complex[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
        {
            X_n[i] = X[N / 2 + i];
            X_n[N / 2 + i] = X[i];
        }
        return X_n;
    }
}
```

Из файлах содержатся значения сигнала экг: 26,48 24,743 19,478 18,407 20,252 23,051 21,028.... и тд это зачения по Y, по X в другом файле, после преобразований, выдаёт чудо график...

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chart2.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Complex complex in danie.FastPFurie)
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(complex.Real, complex.Imaginary);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результатом БПФ является массив комплексных амплитуд. Брать из него действительную и мнимую часть бессмысленно, так как полезную информацию (с точки зрения анализа сигнала) несет только модуль. Построение графика должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
for (int i=0; i < danie.FastPFurie.Length; i++) {
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Complex.Abs(danie.FastPFurie[i]));
}
```

Comment: Уже более похоже, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Для fft нужны равномерные отсчёты, т.е. массив Y с постоянным шагом по X. Данные заносятся в вещественную часть, мнимая заполняется нулями.

После преобразования можно отобразить амплитуду комплексных чисел. Для некоторых целей может также понадобиться фаза.

А мнимую и реальную часть смотреть могут не только лишь все. Мало кто может это делать ©

Для начала стоит потренироваться на заведомо понятных данных - например, заполнить массив синусом или суммой нескольких синусов с разными частотами - на графике амплитуде должны быть большие пики  по числу частот (если частоты попадают в диапазон), и куча пиков маленьких.